Gazebo "not responding" or not opening problem
I'm trying to run a simulation package (neo_simulation2) that my company provided. I have installed ros2-humble and gazebo 11 classic and all ros_gazebo packages required. After setting the environment variables, I used the below command:
ros2 launch neo_simulation2 simulation.launch.py

My terminal gives this outputs:


After this sometimes gazebo opens, freezes and I get the not responding box or sometimes it doesn't open at all and I use the
gzclient --verbose then gazebo opens and freezes. Can anyone tell me what's the problem and a fix for it?
PC settings:
Using ubuntu 22.04 ros2 humble in vmware fusion 13 on a arm64 macbook air m3.
Virtual machine settings: 6gb RAM with 30 gb internal

which "environment variables" have you set? Have you sourced the gazebo/setup.bash as the error message indicates?

I set the environment variables MY_ROBOT and MAP_NAME and I source install/setup.bash and my install directory contains gazebo and its pkgs as well so it should be sourced.
Check out: https://neobotix-docs.de/ros/ros2/installation.html#packages-for-simulation  for what I installed in my workspace.
and https://neobotix-docs.de/ros/ros2/simulation.html  for the environment variables and simulation

Have you sourced the gazebo/setup.bash as the error message indicates?

No when tried to source it, it shows there is no such directory exists

In my docker (jammy) it gets installed in /usr/share/gazebo/setup.bash

Yeah I found it and added it to my .bashrc and sourced it. the errors have gone but still I get the "not responding" box. Is it due to my GPU?

You just can run gazebo from your command line and see if an empty world is launching. It may take a while to fetch models from the server, it can take 1-2min at the first launch.

I just ran it and the same "not responding" box pops up, after 30 secs

other GUI programs do run? Rviz2?

Not installed it yet
